# Show contents of javascript arrays in buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code. How do I make the contents of the array appear on the button? The arrays have a content of 0,1,2,3,4,5. I want the the buttons which are aligned vertically to be as follows:

0
1
2
3
4
5

```js
var family = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(family);
for (var prop in family) {
  document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML += '<div class=col> <button type="button" class="list-group-item"' + prop + '</button></div>';
  console.log(prop);
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <ul id="aaron-family">
      <div class="list-group"></div>
    </ul>
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      j 1 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am voting to close this question, as the problem is caused by a missing `>` on the `<button>` opening tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is working fine now.**

your code was working fine, you just forget to close the `<button>` tag on **appending the HTML**.

```js
var family = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for (var prop in family) {
  document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML += '<div class=col> <button type="button" class="list-group-item">' + prop + '</button></div>';
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <ul id="aaron-family">

        <div class="list-group">

        </div>
      </ul>
      <div class="col">
        1 of 3
      </div>
      <div class="col">j 1 of 3
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this was helpful to you. If there is anything else please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is incorrect as well as the string html you are trying to append, you can change it to (I used string templates for better readability) :

```
family.forEach((value) => {
    document.getElementById('aaron-family').innerHTML += `
        <div class="col">
            <button type="button" class="list-group-item">${value}</button>
        </div>
    `;
});
```